# Hilbert manifolds and embedding

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, hilbert-manifolds

In the Wikipedia article on Hilbert manifolds, it is claimed that every Hilbert manifold can be smoothly embedded onto an open subset of the model Hilbert space. However, no explicit reference is given. Does anybody know a reference.

I must honestly say that I find that result somewhat hard to believe...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[MR0263120](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=263120) (41 #7725)
Eells, J.; Elworthy, K. D.
Open embeddings of certain Banach manifolds.
Ann. of Math. (2) 91 1970 465–485.